# FFMPEG loop not start immediately

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I have this drawtext scrolling vertically `x=10:y=w-mod(max(t-1\,0)*(w+tw)/30\,(w+tw))`

My problem is that when it scroll over whole video it takes around 10 seconds to start loop again and I need to start loop immediately.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
y=h-mod(max(t-1\,0)*(h+th)/30\,h+th)
```

Since you're scrolling vertically from bottom to top, using the width variables will provide undesired results.